# Formtastic Collection_select Unrelated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

Maybe this is the wrong way to go about things - I'll accept any better suggestions if you have them!

We have a simple ordering system - our orders have many milestones and each milestone belongs to an order.

As an aside, each milestone also has assigned users but I didn't want to create a relationship between the two as my users also own the orders...

In my milestone form, I have the following:

```
<%= semantic_form_for([@order, @milestone]) do |f| %>
.....
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :milestone_user %><br />
    <%= f.input :milestone_user, :as => :radio, :collection => User.find(:all, :order => "name ASC") %>
  </div>
....
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is all marvellous and I can see my users rendered as radio buttons.

The issue is that when I save, I'm left with the user id instead of the name.

How can I transfer this in to a name??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you have the correct associations in your models the following should work (just did it yesterday in a View template)

```
place.cplace.name
```

where, in my models:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :cplace_id, :cmoney_id, :copen_id, :description

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :cplace
...
end

class Cplace < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :description

  has_many :places
...
end
```

So even though my cplace (Category place) field in Place model is named cplace_id, you can rescue the name or any other field by

```
place.cplace.name
```

where place is an instance variable containing the Place ... instance...

hope it helps, and happy coding!

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for as my users don't own the milestone.

Comment: kinda late. but... you may take the id you get from params and use something like `Milestone.find(params[:id]).name`